# How to use remember me function in my android login application

Tags: android

I am using the code for remember my username and password. i have tried a lot of hours for the code for remember my username name and password but i cant success in it.

Here is my code which i have download from internet but it didn't work for me.

I have declared this variable in the extends activity.

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static final String PREFS_USER = "prefsUsername";
public static final String PREFS_PASS = "prefsPassword";
```

after that I have also declare different variable like below.

```
public String PREFS_USERS;
public String PREFS_PASS;

String username;
String upass;
```

and in the click listener i have given the following code.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);   

username = etUsername.getText().toString();
upass = etPassword.getText().toString();

getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
    .edit()
    .putString(PREFS_USERS, username)
    .putString(PREFS_PASS, upass)
    .commit();
```

and at the time at retry i have return the following code in the `oncreate` activity to retry my user name and password.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

username = pref.getString(PREFS_USERS, "");
upass = pref.getString(PREFS_PASS, "");
```

But when I run the application i cant get the username and password.First time when i load the application i checked the remember me check box after log in and log out back from the application and close the application and when come back to it.it was not saved for me.

Comment: you can use sqllite to store username and password and check if already exist.

Comment: Check your shredpreference xml file from DDMS->Fiel Explorer->data-> data -> your package -> shared Pref.  does your value saved in your shaed pref xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in declaring the variables

you have declared

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
public static final String PREFS_USER = "prefsUsername";
public static final String PREFS_PASS = "prefsPassword";

public String PREFS_USERS;
public String PREFS_PASS; //assigned null here
```

`.putString(PREFS_PASS, upass)` //here value of PREFS_PASS is null

**Use the following code**

better do like the folowing

```
public String PREFS_USERNAME= "prefsUsername";
public String PREFS_PASSWORD="prefsPassword";
```

Store the data as using following code

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);   

passwordInString = password.getText().toString();
userNameInString = username.getText().toString();

getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE)
    .edit()
    .putString(PREFS_USERNAME, userNameInString)
    .putString(PREFS_PASSWORD, passwordInString)
    .commit();
```

retrieve the data like the following

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);

String usernameName = pref.getString(PREFS_USERNAME, "");
String upassWord = pref.getString(PREFS_PASSWORD, "");
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 2):

It should look something like this (obviously you can use global vars so you dont have to specify them in several places):

```
String PREFS = "MyPrefs";
SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override 
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) { 
    super.onCreate(icicle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, 0);

    //check if the remember option has been check before
    boolean rememberMe = mPrefs.getBoolean("rememberMe", false);

    if(rememberMe == true){
        //get previously stored login details
        String login = mPrefs.getString("login", null);
        String upass = mPrefs.getString("password", null);

        if(login != null && pass != null){
            //fill input boxes with stored login and pass
            EditText loginEbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_box);
            EditText passEbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass_box);
            loginEbx.setText(login);
            passEbx.setText(upass);

            //set the check box to 'checked' 
            CheckBox rememberMeCbx = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.remeber_cbx);
            rememberMeCbx.setChecked(true);
        }
    }
}

private void saveLoginDetails(){
    //fill input boxes with stored login and pass
    EditText loginEbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.login_box);
    EditText passEbx = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass_box);
    String login = loginEbx.getText().toString();
    String upass = passEbx.getText().toString();

    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
    e.putBoolean("rememberMe", true);
    e.putString("login", login);
    e.putString("password", upass);
    e.commit();
}

private void removeLoginDetails(){
    Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
    e.putBoolean("rememberMe", false);
    e.remove("login");
    e.remove("password");
    e.commit();
}
```

You would probably call the saveLoginDetails() & removeLoginDetails() methods in the OnClick listener:

```
CheckBox rememberMeCbx = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.remeber_cbx);
boolean isChecked = rememberMeCbx.isChecked();
if(isChecked){
    saveLoginDetails();
}else{
    removeLoginDetails();
}
```

I hope you can find it useful

Answer (score 0):

U can do this.. create a boolean variable with default value `"false"` and set a boolean value to true when user choses for `rememberMe` and put an `if condition` before validating user password and other stuff.. and use the boolean value in this condition..

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences myPrefs; 

onCreate()
{
    myPrefs=this.getSharedPreferences("PREF_NAME",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(myPrefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false))
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,SeeRecordsActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

on signIn button:

```
boolean c=chkbox.isChecked();

if(c==true)
{  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("firstTime", true);
    editor.commit();
}
```